# Same IP range, Different Subnet range

Tags: networking, subnet

Simple query. Just wondering, if I had one computer

```
PC-A
IP:      192.168.0.10
Subnet:  255.255.0.0
```

and another

```
PC-B
IP:      192.168.0.15
Subnet:  255.255.255.0
```

both on the same physical network, should I be able to ping PC-B from PC-A?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they should be able to ping each other, in both directions: the reason is that the network of PC-B is wholly contained inside the network of PC-A, and PC-A is located in that portion of its network which **also** belongs to the network of PC-B.

The network of PC-B is

```
192.168.0.1 <-> 192.168.0.254
```

while the network of PC-A is

```
192.168.0.1 <-> 192.168.255.254
```

**EDIT**:

> what if i had PCB on 192.168.1.15/255.255.255.0. I am assuming that i am wouldnt be able to ping as the IP range is different?

Right, let me explain why: if you try to ping something outside your LAN, the ICMP (=ping) packets are routed to your gateway, which says they belong to a different LAN, and thus sends them away on its outer interface (=toward the outer world): no packets are sent on the same physical network, just the one addressed to the gateway, which PC-B cannot, and will not intercept.

Despite what is said below, routers ...

> ... are supposed to honor the split horizon rule, which says that you do not forward packets received on one interface back through the same interface. That can cause routing loops. Router are supposed to drop packets with the same source and destination network

as correctly pointed out by @RonMaupin (kudos for the RFCs, I was still searching for them when you posted them!).

Besides, there is a simple way to test this: delete the default route to your local LAN (on Linux, this is done thru

```
 ip route del 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0
```

if `192.168.0.0/24` is your network and `eth0` your interface), but leave the default gateway untouched. Now, all communications to other machines on your LAN will have to be mediated by the gateway. You will see that most routers (exceptions?) do not allow `ping`'ing LAN machines, and this includes my EdgeMax RouterOS and my Buffalo DD-Wrt.

Comment: Thanks, what if i had PCB on 192.168.1.15/255.255.255.0. I am assuming that i am wouldnt be able to ping as the IP range is different?

Comment: @StephenPefanis Right!! Let me explain why: if you try to ping something **outside** your LAN, the ICMP (=ping) packets are routed to your gateway, which says they belong to a different LAN, and thus sends them away on its outer interface (=toward the outer world): no packets are sent on the same physical network, just the one addressed to the gateway, which PC-B cannot, and will not intercept.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Actually, that depends on what the router thinks the net mask is (and possibly _it's_ address).  Some routers will effectively forward the packet back out the same interface based on _it's_ idea of whether the destination is on that subnet or not (and there was even originally an ICMP code it could send to the source telling it the destination is actually on the same cable, but that code has been deprecated as a security flaw).

Comment: @MAP, routers are supposed to honor the split horizon rule, which says that you do not forward packets received on one interface back through the same interface. That can cause routing loops. Router are supposed to drop packets with the same source and destination network.

Comment: @RonMaupin That's why my comment was qualified with a "depends" and "some", in the same way you qualify with "supposed to".  As we both know there are myriad differences and (in my 30 year perspective), split horizon is new and I still encounter devices that don't do it right.

Comment: @MAP, split-horizon is hardly new. The very first routers implemented it. It is built into all routing protocols from the very first one (RIP).

Comment: @RonMaupin, I wrote one of those first routers (in 1982), we supported RIP and would do the ICMP redirect, one does not imply the other.  It was actually part of our experiences with ICMP redirect that got it deprecated.  In the original design it was anticipated that end nodes would not all know what the netmask was, so every host was reached through the router and the ICMP message was intended to help them learn.  But they weren't initially required to.

Comment: @MAP, the original RIP RFC, [RFC 1058, Routing Information Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1058), from 1988, has the split-horizon rule built in. See Section 2.2.1, Split Horizon.

Comment: Routers and RIP predate that RFC by almost a decade.

Comment: @MAP, that may be, but my point is that what you wrote, "_split horizon is new_" is not at all accurate when its been in RIP for nearly 30 years. That is many generations in network time. The commercial Internet had not yet been envisioned in 1988. You can hardly call it new, and it has been built into the later routers and routing protocols from their inceptions.

Comment: Thanks all for the information. It makes sense now. I was just playing with some things to learn more